# google authentication and access token after revoke

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-authentication

I am using OAuth2.0 google api and after signing in with google+ I get authentication token and access token. The authentication token I can successfully exchange into refresh token.
My problem is the following:
On first login the app gets the authentication token and access token.
If the user, in the 10 minutes of authentication token ttl, revokes the app and then signs in again, I saw I get the same tokens as in first login, making them useless because they were revoked.
How can I get new tokens after revoke from google within those 10 minutes?

Comment: What is this 10 minute TTL you are talking about?

Comment: authentication token (one time only) is valld for only 10 minutes

Comment: Google access tokens should be good for one hour.

Answer (score 1):

Your application should do three things.

1) When a user signs in, save their refresh token/access token in case it has changed.

2) If the app gets an error when using an access token, use the refresh token to get a new one.

3) If the app gets an error using the refresh token, prompt the user to reauthenticate.

It shouldn't matter in your app if/when a user revokes access. Either the token is valid or it isn't. If it's not valid you prompt the user to get a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that on sign-in with google+ I get the same authentication code as before. I don't understand why google gives me the same revoked authentication token and not a new one. I would like to receive a new authentication token without checking the validity of the refresh token